# Cordova show a screen with a redundant black shapes

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, genymotion

I created a cordova 4.1.0 project for android, when i run the project in virtual genymotion , i see in screen have a black shapes is redundant. I don't know how to remove it.

[image]

Anyone can help me?

Comment: How are the shapes redundant?

Comment: @JesseMonroy650: You can see the image, i donot know why that shape appear. I just create a project, build and run it in Genymotion

Comment: You use the word "redundant". I see no "redundant".